# How to eliminate horizontal scroll bar in drag & drop div

Tags: css, html, drag-and-drop

I'm having a problem with a drag & drop UI.  When i drag items from the left, you can see that they are scrolling to the right within that div a fair ways before allowing me to drop on the calendar [(see exhibit A)](http://screencast.com/t/paVbt9dt4)

I'm not a CSS expert, but i understand that setting:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

...Is supposed to stop that from happening, however i've tried it on the parent div and the parent's parent and no luck - still scrolling horizontally. I'm using the latest versions of Chrome & Firefox.

[Here's the code i'm working with.](http://pastie.org/5699924)

Comment: Do you have a set width on the element you're using overflow on?

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding fix Width on this class

```
    .woContainer
        {   width: 150px;
            height: 550px;
            max-width: 150px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
```